# Game freezes on "Insert Disc 3" screen

Tags: legend-of-dragoon

After travelling back to disc 2 to do some shopping my game continually freezes when I try to progress back to disc 3.  It goes to the insert disc screen and when I change the disc I can hear the disc spin for a few seconds but the game never loads.

Is there a fix/workaround for this bug?

Comment: Playstation 1, I guess. There are a few tricks I learned. First - Clean the CD and the laser lens (be careful with the lens!). Everything nice and clean? Good. Now, pick up your ps1 and turn it upside down or turn it sideways. Sometimes that can help with a game that doesn't want to load.

Comment: I am playing on a Playstation 2.  I played through this game several times on a Playstation 1 and never had this issue.

Comment: I see. Well, I only ever had to use this trick with my ps1, so I don't know if it works with a ps2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I found online, this is a common issue when playing LOD on a Playstation 2.  While I was not able to find a reliable workaround anywhere I did figure one out that I have tested several times without fail.

When you are getting ready to head back to disc 3 you board the Queen Fury and save your game while on the world map.  Turn off the game and switch to disc 3.  Load your game and make port in the next town.  Since every disc has the world map for every other disc on it, using this method lets you bypass the insert disc screen altogether.  (I thought of this after power leveling for around an hour with the wrong disc in)